# How can I a catch an unexpectedly reset in a microcontroller

Tags: c, flash, exception, microcontroller, reset

I'm working with a MCF51EM256 Freescale microcontroller and I've some problems with the flash programming.

In order to make my software persistant I'm trying to store some variables in the external flash memory to recover from unexpected shutdowns.

Sometimes, when I test my work shutting down the MCU, it is constantly reset. It is probably caused by an error writing any flash address, during the shutdown, which after is not able to read properly.

My question is, there is a way to catch this fatal exception which causes the reset in my micro?

[MCF51EM256 Reference Manual](http://cache.nxp.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/MCF51EM256RM.pdf?fpsp=1&WT_TYPE=Reference%20Manuals&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation&fileExt=.pdf)

Comment: If it's a watchdog firing, probably not.  Otherwise, can you put a breakpoint on the reset vector and/or install a reset handler that performs a stack/register dump?

Comment: Also, if the flash data storage is corrupted because of 'normal' software development 'issues', you should be detecting the bad data and issuing an  error information, or using two banks, CRCing them and using them alternately, or using some other error-mitigation strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the described behaviour is indeed caused by the reason you assume, you could protect yourself from using inconsistantly written values from flash with a "magic word" written to a known location at the end of your flash write.

On shutdown, clear your "magic word", then flash your stored values as you do already, and finally write the "magic word" (like 0x31419265) to a known flash location.

On startup, check this value. If it's the value you expect, you can use the other variables, if not, you must assume flash write has failed and ignore them (you'd need some sensible defaults then, I assume).

Comment: With flash you can change individual bits in one direction but not the other, you cant clear then restore a magic word in a known location without one of those two actions requiring you to erase a whole block.

Comment: A variation on this would be to add the new set of data at the end, in the erased portion of the flash, with a checksum of some sort.  on boot scan the flash looking for the end (erased portion, usually all 0xFFs, easy to test for with your specific part), perhaps checking the data blocks on the way or work from the back forward.  Use the last one with a good checksum.

Comment: As mfro is saying, mark the data in a way such that the last thing written ties the data set together, making it so you can tell if it is a complete data set or not then handle the or not case.  How you mark it can be solved a number of ways.  magic numbers, checksums, implement a file system, etc.

Comment: Thanks @mfro. I'm tryied to use a magic word like u say but the problem persists. Probably I'm doing something wrong when I write the flash memory.